# how to animate div box from left to right or right to left when scroll web page

Tags: jquery-animate, box, scrollspy

i want to animate div box from left to righ and right to left.

suppose i have a 2 box with bootstrap classes`example :

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 id="leftToRight"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 id="RightToLeft"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

now i want to animate #leftToRight id from left to right and #RightToLeft from righ to left.
when scroll web page.

I see many website in which this type of animation is applied.
I am very curious to know how it is happen.

Comment: Can you show what you have done or tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wheel` event to answer your question:

```js
$(function() {

$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {

 var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

 if (delta > 0)  //On scroll down
  {
    $('#RightToLeft').animate({
    left:  "-=10px"
    },5);
    
    $('#LeftToRight').animate({
    left:  "+=10px"
    },5);
  }
 else  //This is added for reverse animation on scroll up
  {
    $('#RightToLeft').animate({
    left:  "+=10px"
    },5);
    
    $('#LeftToRight').animate({
    left:  "-=10px"
    },5);
  }
  
  return false; // this line is only added so the whole page won't scroll in the demo
});
});
```

```css
#RightToLeft{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#LeftToRight{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.row{
  margin: auto;
  width:90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="LeftToRight">Left to Right</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="RightToLeft">Right to Left</div>
     </div>
</div>
```